# gitui doesnt recognize git repository refuses to start

Tags: git

I am learning gitui (https://github.com/extrawurst/gitui), after installing gitui on my system, i did the following things to run gitui in a new git repository

```
[giga@chad ~/projects]$ git init css
Initialized empty Git repository in /mnt/library/projects/css/.git/
[giga@chad ~/projects]$ cd css
[giga@chad ~/projects/css]$ gitui
Error: invalid path
please run gitui inside of a non-bare git repository
```

gitui throws error complaining to run it inside a git repository. but it is infact running under a git repository.

I tried this to add content to repo

```
[giga@chad ~/projects/css]$ echo 'joke' > index.html
[giga@chad ~/projects/css]$ git add index.html
[giga@chad ~/projects/css]$ git commit
[main (root-commit) 5945cda]  Changes to be committed: new file:   index.html
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 index.html
[giga@chad ~/library/projects/css]$ gitui
Error: invalid path
please run gitui inside of a non-bare git repository
```

what am i missing. how to successfully run gitui to be able to use its interactive features on my `css` repository.

Comment: You just created the repo. That’s called a bare repo. Make some commits

Comment: @DanielA.White i did try. it didnt work. here non-bare repo means a repo not created using --bare.